# error adding value to a field which is also an app

Tags: ios, swift, podio

I am trying to create a new item in an app but I am having an error when I try to add value to a field with type `app`. I can add values to other fields (field type `category`) and can create the item no problem. is there a specific way of adding a connection to other apps when creating a `PKTItem`?

here is my code to create the item:

```
let item = PKTItem(forAppWithID: devApp)
        print("item.itemID: \(item?.itemID)")

        //service field is of type category with external id: service
        item?.setValue(3, forField: "service")
        //pet field is of type app with external id: pet
        item?.setValue(testPet, forField: "pet")

        item?.save().onComplete({(response, error) in
            if (error != nil){
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
            else{
                if let responseObject = response as? PKTResponse{
                    if let body = responseObject.body as? [String: Any]{
                        print("body: \(body)")
                        if let itemID = body["app_item_id"] as? UInt{
                            self.updateAppointmentItem(itemID: itemID)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

the error i'm having is 
`'Invalid field value: Field value '1089261271' is not of expected class '( PKTItem )' for value class 'PKTAppItemFieldValue'.'`

Answer (score 0):

As in the [source file](https://github.com/podio/podio-objc/blob/push/PodioKit/Common/Models/PKTItem.m), the initializer expects an unsigned integer

> itemForAppWithID:(NSUInteger)

Try changing `devApp` to an unsigned integer and pass in, like so

```
PKTItem(forAppWithID: UInt(devApp))
```